How to Get Text Value from PlateJS
I found PlateJS has API to desrialize string html into editor values:
editor.api.html.deserialize({element:"<p>Hi!</P>"})

I need a method in reverse, so it takes the value after change and convert it to plain string html like:
"<p><strong>Hi!</strong> It's me.</p>"

How can I achieve this or convert children to string?
onValueChange pass a value with this type {value: ValueOf<E>} where value has children property.

Did you mean SlateJS instead of PlateJS?
SlateJs is a "framework for building rich text editor".
Their website describes how to both serialize and deserialize...https://docs.slatejs.org/concepts/10-serializing

@RayWallace No, I meant PlateJS, which is built around SlateJS for React.
But I think this will work. I'll try it and see how it goes.
